# Check every MySQL query result row and do an action

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 frames, and a MySQL table full of elements.

The first frame has a dropdown menu and a submit button. The values (total 15) of dropdown list are taken from a MySQL database with the query `SELECT DISTINCT (table_column) table_name`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<?php
    include_once "CONNECT_TO_DB_SCRIPT.php";
    $query_ak = 'SELECT DISTINCT (column_name) FROM table_name';
    $result = mysql_query($query_ak) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<select name="exa">
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['ak_ex'].'">'.$row['ak_ex'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="GO!" name="go"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So now I want in the second frame to check if we select a value of the dropdown list to show the equivalent part of MySQL table where the values of a certain column_name are the same with the value I submited in dropdown menu.

Example: `SELECT * FROM table_name where column_name= value_of_dropdown_menu.`

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
<?php
include_once "CONNECT_TO_DB_script.php";
$query_ak='SELECT DISTINCT (column_name) FROM table_name';
$result_ak = mysql_query ($query_ak) or die (mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['go'])) { //checks if submit button has a value or it is NULL

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ak)) {
    if ($_POST["exa"] == "$row['ak_ex']") {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name where column_name='.$row['ak_ex'].'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

…

close connection
?>
```

Comment: Note that distinct is not a function

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
<form method="post">
<?php
    include_once "CONNECT_TO_DB_SCRIPT.php";
    $query_ak = 'SELECT DISTINCT (column_name) FROM table_name';
    $result = mysql_query($query_ak) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<select name="exa">
<?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['ak_ex'].'">'.$row['ak_ex'].'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="GO!" name="go"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['go'])) {
$a = $row['exa'];
$query_ak='SELECT DISTINCT (column_name) FROM table_name';
$result_ak = mysql_query ($query_ak) or die (mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_ak)) {
        if ($row['col_name'] == $a) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name where column_name='".$row['ak_ex']."' ";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: didnt work i think that "$a = $row['exa'];" has something wrong

Comment: Use `$a = $_REQUEST['exa']` & check whether it's working or not.

Comment: still nothing.No error displaying neither any result.

Comment: i think that there is a mistake on "if(isset($_REQUEST['go']))" command

Answer (score -1):

Please note that your `SQL` result is from a `mysql_query()` function but you are using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` to get data from it. Use `mysql_fetch_array()`
Also you are going through a very hard process to get you posted data.and some syntax erorrs. in second frame go like this:

```
<?php

    include_once "CONNECT_TO_DB_script.php";
    if (isset($_POST['go']))    {   //checks if submit button has a value or it is NULL
            $query= 'SELECT * FROM table_name where column_name=\''.$_POST["exa"].'\'';
            $result= mysql_query($query) or die ('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
.
.
.
close connection
?>
```

Comment: Probably shouldn't be recommending functions from a deprecated and insecure API

Comment: You are right. `mysql_fetch_array()` and `mysql()` family is departed from new versions of `php` and it is best to use `mysqli()` family. you can use this:[W3schools mysqli tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: Also probably shouldn't be recommending that link - although it seems like petty rivalry to me ;-) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: As @Strawberry mentioned correctly (thanks to him or her, I learned a lot) it is best to use official docs like [php.net mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)